# Found screens with the same name nested inside one another and app keeps crashing on android device

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I working on a mobile app for a long time. But after suddenly it is acting weird. Weird thing is that application navigation is working fine on iOS device but on the other hand on Android device it's keep crashing. Even i did not touch the navigation code for a long time.

**error screenshot attached. and code also added.**
[image]

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Image, SafeAreaView, Pressable, Text} from 'react-native';
import Colors from '../common/Colors';
import Fonts from '../common/Fonts';
import {
  widthPercentageToDP as wp,
  heightPercentageToDP as hp,
} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
//React-native navigation API
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';

// Application Screens
import Splash from '../screens/splash/Splash';
import OnBoarding from '../screens/onBoarding/OnBoarding';
import SignInMain from '../screens/auth/SignInMain';
import SignInMobileOTP from '../screens/auth/SignInMobileOTP';
import SignInEmail from '../screens/auth/SignInEmail';
import SignInMobileNo from '../screens/auth/SignInMobileNo';
import SignUp from '../screens/auth/SignUp';
import SignUpSocialMedia from '../screens/auth/SignUpSocialMedia';
import HomeBlueColarJobs from '../screens/blueColarJob/HomeBlueColarJobs';
import BlueColarJobListing from '../screens/blueColarJob/BlueColarJobListing';
import HomeWhiteColarJob from '../screens/whiteColarJob/HomeWhiteColarJob';
import DrawerComponent from '../components/drawerNavigator/DrawerComponent';
import Dashboard from '../screens/dashboard/Dashboard';
import UserProfile from '../screens/profile/UserProfile';
import Notification from '../screens/notification/Notification';
import EditProfileInfo from '../screens/profile/EditProfileInfo';
import RecommendedJobs from '../screens/jobs/RecommendedJobs';
import MySavedJobs from '../screens/jobs/MySavedJobs';
import AboutUs from '../screens/innovationGroup/AboutUs';
import OfficesLocation from '../screens/innovationGroup/OfficesLocation';
import TermsAndConditions from '../screens/innovationGroup/TermsAndConditions';
import FAQs from '../screens/innovationGroup/FAQs';
import OTPSendingOptions from '../screens/forgetPassword/OTPSendingOptions';
import ForgetPasswordScreen from '../screens/forgetPassword/ForgetPasswordScreen';
import AdditionalDetailsForm from '../screens/additionalForms/AdditionalDetailsForm';
import TechSupport from '../screens/onBoarding/TechSupport';
// Vector icon import for navigation icons
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import Fontisto from 'react-native-vector-icons/Fontisto';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import MyJobs from '../screens/jobs/MyJobs';
import AllJobs from '../screens/allJobs/AllJobs';
import JobDetails from '../screens/blueColarJob/BlueColarJobDetails';

// Constants for the navigation
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

// User Profile Navigator
export const UserProfileNavigator = () =>{
  return(
    <Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName="UserProfile"
    screenOptions={{headerShown: true, headerTransparent: true}}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'UserProfile'}
        component={UserProfile}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />

      <Stack.Screen
        name={'EditProfileInfo'}
        component={EditProfileInfo}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
} ;

// Home Navigator
export const BlueCollarNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="AllJobs"
      screenOptions={{headerShown: true, headerTransparent: true}}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'HomeBlueColarJobs'}
        component={HomeBlueColarJobs}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'BlueColarJobListing'}
        component={BlueColarJobListing}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'HomeWhiteColarJob'}
        component={HomeWhiteColarJob}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'AllJobs'}
        component={AllJobs}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

// Authentication Navigator
export const AuthNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{headerShown: true, headerTransparent: true}}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'SignInMain'}
        component={SignInMain}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'SignInEmail'}
        component={SignInEmail}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'SignUp'}
        component={SignUp}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'SignUpSocialMedia'}
        component={SignUpSocialMedia}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'SignInMobileNo'}
        component={SignInMobileNo}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'SignInMobileOTP'}
        component={SignInMobileOTP}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'OTPSendingOptions'}
        component={OTPSendingOptions}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'TechSupport'}
        component={TechSupport}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'ForgetPasswordScreen'}
        component={ForgetPasswordScreen}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
// Authentication Navigator 
export const DashBoarNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{headerShown: true, headerTransparent: true}}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'Dashboard'}
        component={Dashboard}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'MySavedJobs'}
        component={MySavedJobs}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'RecommendedJobs'}
        component={RecommendedJobs}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'MyJobs'}
        component={MyJobs}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'JobDetails'}
        component={JobDetails}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'AdditionalDetailsForm'}
        component={AdditionalDetailsForm}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

// Bottom Tab Navigator
export const TabNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="HomeBlueColarJobs"
      screenOptions={({route}) => ({
        tabBarStyle: {height: hp('10%'), paddingBottom: hp('4%')},
        tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
          let iconName;
          let focusedColor = focused ? '#9237E3' : '#4F5B79';
          let focusedSize = focused ? hp('4%') : hp('3.5%');

          if (route.name === 'Dashboard') {
            iconName = focused ? 'view-dashboard' : 'view-dashboard-outline';
          } else if (route.name === 'Jobs') {
            iconName = focused ? 'clipboard-text' : 'clipboard-text-outline';
          } else if (route.name === 'Notification') {
            iconName = focused ? 'bell' : 'bell-outline';
          } else if (route.name === 'UserProfile') {
            iconName = focused ? 'account-circle' : 'account-circle-outline';
          }

          // You can return any component that you like here!
          return (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name={iconName}
              size={focusedSize}
              color={focusedColor}
            />
          );
        },
      })}
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: '#9237E3',
        inactiveTintColor: '#4F5B79',
        labelStyle: {fontFamily: Fonts.poppinsBold, fontSize: hp('1%')},
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Dashboard"
        component={DashBoarNavigator}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Jobs"
        component={AllJobs}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Notification"
        component={Notification}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="UserProfile"
        component={UserProfileNavigator}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

// Drawer Navigator
export const DrawerNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerContent={props => <DrawerComponent {...props} />}
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        drawerType: 'front',
        drawerActiveBackgroundColor: Colors.lightPurple,
        drawerActiveTintColor: Colors.blueViolet,
        drawerInactiveTintColor:'#9c9b9b',
        drawerLabelStyle: {
          marginLeft: wp('-3%'),
          fontFamily: Fonts.latoBold,
          fontSize: hp('1.7%'),
        },
        drawerStyle: {
          height: hp('95%'),
          borderTopRightRadius: hp('4%'),
          borderBottomRightRadius: hp('4%'),
        },
      }}>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name={'Dashboard'}
        component={TabNavigation}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          drawerIcon: ({color}) => (
            <MaterialIcons color={color} name="dashboard" size={hp('3%')} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name={'Profile'}
        component={UserProfile}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          drawerIcon: ({color}) => (
            <Feather color={color} name="user" size={hp('3%')} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name={'Applied Jobs'}
        component={MyJobs}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          drawerIcon: ({color}) => (
            <FontAwesome color={color} name="list-alt" size={hp('3%')} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name={'Recommended Jobs'}
        component={RecommendedJobs}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          drawerIcon: ({color}) => (
            <FontAwesome color={color} name="list-alt" size={hp('3%')} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name={'My Saved Jobs'}
        component={MySavedJobs}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          drawerIcon: ({color}) => (
            <FontAwesome color={color} name="list-alt" size={hp('3%')} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name={'Notifications'}
        component={Notification}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          drawerIcon: ({color}) => (
            <Fontisto color={color} name="bell" size={hp('3%')} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name={'About Us'}
        component={AboutUs}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          drawerIcon: ({color}) => (
            <AntDesign color={color} name="infocirlceo" size={hp('3%')} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name={'Contact Us'}
        component={OfficesLocation}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          drawerIcon: ({color}) => (
            <MaterialIcons color={color} name="contact-phone" size={hp('3%')} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name={'FAQs'}
        component={FAQs}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          drawerIcon: ({color}) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              color={color}
              name="message-question-outline"
              size={hp('3%')}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name={'Privacy Policy'}
        component={TermsAndConditions}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          drawerIcon: ({color}) => (
            <MaterialIcons
              color={color}
              name="policy"
              size={hp('3%')}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

// Initial Navigator
export const InitialNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Splash">
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'Splash'}
        component={Splash}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'OnBoarding'}
        component={OnBoarding}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'SignInMain'}
        component={AuthNavigator}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name={'Drawer'}
        component={DrawerNavigator}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 `SignInMain` elements in your navigation. One in `Initial Navigator` and one in `Authentication Navigator`

**Initial Navigator**

```js
export const InitialNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Splash">
      ...
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'SignInMain'}
        component={AuthNavigator}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      ...
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

**Authentication Navigator**

```js
// Authentication Navigator
export const AuthNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{headerShown: true, headerTransparent: true}}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name={'SignInMain'}
        component={SignInMain}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      ...
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Whilst this is not necessarily forbidden, it is best to fix this issue since this can give unwanted results. Fix this by changing the name of one of the 2 components and name in your navigation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have change the component name in "Initial navigator". It's working now not getting that error that i have show in the screenshot. But still crashing , i hope it will be another bug.